# Rendering a Django xml template (not html), how do you create output with no newlines?

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I'm rendering a Django xml template (not html), how do you create output with no newlines?  So the django template file has newlines in it, but I want to render the output as one long string of text (since it is for data transmission) with no newlines.  Is there a way to render the template and then strip out all newlines?

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your template with `{% spaceless %} ... {% endspaceless %}`.

Comment: spaceless is a good general tag to include in production templates. Gets rid of unnecessary whitespace (and precious bytes!)